# Change tint color for sharing via Notes app in iOS

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, uiactivityviewcontroller

On iOS 11, if user shares a link via Notes app from my app, the Cancel/Done buttons are white (on white background). How to change those buttons tint?

I am sharing a link like this:

```
    let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [myShareUrl], applicationActivities: nil)
    presentViewController(activityVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Here's an example how currently it looks like:
[image]

I am also adjust NavTint color in AppDelegate like this:

```
    UINavigationBar.appearance().shadowImage  = UIImage()
    UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = .clearColor()
    UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor    = .whiteColor()
    UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(
        UIImage(), forBarMetrics: UIBarMetrics.Default
    )
```

**EDIT**

I've tried setting tint color like this, before presenting `UIActivityViewController`:

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.tintColor = UIColor.appRed()
```

And while it worked on iOS9, does not work on iOS11.

Comment: I don't think you can. These buttons are a part of Notes' Share Extension. You can't make any changes to other app's extension.

Comment: I am not sure if you seen how sharing via Notes looks like on iOS11, but in my image in top left/right there are buttons like Done and Cancel, but they are white. So, yes, somehow I can change the tint color.

Comment: Can you show an example where this notes extension have a different UI than what it is in the above screenshot?

Comment: Here you go: https://support.apple.com/library/content/dam/edam/applecare/images/en_US/ios/ios11-iphone7-notes-add-attachment-to-notes.jpg

Comment: Exactly. The link you gave is the default UI for Notes Extension. I don't understand how are you getting the one that you attached as the screenshot in your question.

Comment: Did you figure this out ?

Answer (score 1):

Set this before you show

```
UIView.appearance().tintColor
```

Then reset after dismissal to restore - ie within `activityViewController.completionWithItemsHandler`